# Рекуррентная нейросеть очень быстро сходится к одному решению

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, pytorch

На основе GRU делаю нейросеть для прогноза на день вперед. На входе обучения батч вида [BatchNr, DayNr, DayFeatures].
После нескольких батчей **на выходе из GRU слоя все время получаю одинаковые тензоры** (на входе тензоры разные, хоть и очень похожие). Входные тензоры (1 день) примерно такие [0,0,1,-1,-1,1,0,0.5, ...... ,22,12,2022] (вход по большей части в диапазоне -1..1, но пара мест есть числа вида 2022). На выходе ожидаю что-то вида [0,0,0.2,0.9,1,1,1,1,0] (диапазон строго 0..1).

Перепробовал всё что смог: пробовал LSTM, менял loss, добавлял dropout, менял полносвязные слои (от 1 до 3), менял функции активации, менял число слоев GRU n_layers (от 1 до 3) и размер скрытого состояния hidden_dim (от 10 до 300), менял оптимизатор, добавлял штраф за одинаковые тензоры на выходе. Без fc0 немного хуже. В чем я ошибся?

```py
class GRUNet_minimum(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, n_layers, hyp_fc1, hyp_fc2, drop_prob=0.0):
        super(GRUNet_minimum, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.n_layers = n_layers

        self.fc0 = nn.Linear(input_dim, input_dim)
        self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size=input_dim, hidden_size=hidden_dim, num_layers=n_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)
        self.prelu = nn.ELU()
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
        self.evaluate_mode = False
        self.loss_std = nn.MSELoss().to(device)

    def forward(self, x, h):
        x1=self.fc0(x)
        # создаю первоначальное состояние - всегда нули
        h = torch.zeros(self.n_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim).to(device)
        out, h = self.gru( x1, h)
        out = out[:, -1, : ];
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.sigmoid(out)
        return out, h
```

Кусок обучения

```py
for X, y in tqdm(data_loader, total=num_batches, desc='Training'):
    h = model.init_hidden(batch_size)
    output, h = model(X, h)
    loss = get_loss(output, y, loss_function, mask)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Если нужно дополню код (просто он довольно объемный).

По результатам комментариев:

1. скрытое состояние обнуляется перед каждым батчем (пробовал не обнулять - никак не влияет в моем случае).
2. В одном месте ошибся. Dataset length около 1000. Sequence len = пробовал от 10 до 400 (400 это в ущерб длине датасета).
3. Не важно что я подаю на входе (точнее какие прошлые дни) - на выходе константа. Когда смотрю график предсказаний он одинаковый с точностью до 5 знака после запятой.
4. Переобучение может давать одинаковый (константный) результат **на тестовых** данных, но у меня и **на обучающих** данных результат константный. Замеряю стандартное отклонение данных (по колонкам) перед GRU - получаю stddev около 0,26. Сразу после GRU stddev = 0,0 . (Ухищрениями с дополнительным loss дотягиваю его до 0,001-0,1 и даже больше, но финальный результат не меняется). Вместо GRU-RNN-LSTM ставлю полносвязную минисетку и обучение идет действительно как "ставим в прогноз последний день" (ну почти). Т.е. либо неправильно данные в пакете, либо еще что-то. Но постарался всё что можно перепроверить (насколько позволяет мой разум).

Разумеется приведенный код только костяк. Пробовал разное. В частности перед выходом несколько полносвязных слоев. Именно они выучивают характерные закономерности (типа: ночью -- холодно, днем -- тепло) и выдают на выходе изо дня в день с точностью до какого-то там знака после запятой.

Comment: проверьте сигналы, может идёт потеря до 0, добавьте нормализацию или что там для увеличения сигнала. и до кучи https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html  смотрели ли это pip install pytorch-forecasting

Comment: Нормализацию пытаюсь делать полносвязным слоем x1=self.fc0(x). Перед GRU сигналы разные. Сазу после GRU - одинаковые (буквально за пару эпох). Данных мало - sequence length порядка 800 записей.

forecasting буду смотреть.

Comment: 800 - это ничто. можно не браться. поэтому и фигня. а так возьмите какой-нить yolo и в конце lstm-ы, как понимаю (а я на эту тему забил) один lstm- один шаг назад. попробуйте их поболее.

Comment: вот посотрите прогноз, но без памяти прошлых событий (без lstm-ов и т.п.) https://www.kaggle.com/code/hanjoonchoe/cnn-time-series-forecasting-with-pytorch  ну и поищите популярную тему предсказание температуры - weather temperature forecasting pytorch lstm - к примеру уже с lstm   https://levelup.gitconnected.com/forecasting-walmart-quarterly-revenue-pytorch-lstm-example-b4e4b20862a7

Comment: Так а какие тензоры вы получаете на выходе, почему вы не написали? И да, если данных мало и фичи не богатые, то самое лучшее предсказание на следующий день - это значение предыдущего дня. Не удивлюсь, если у вас это и получается. Ну плюс чуть-чуть от позавчера, возможно и т.п.

Comment: это может быть связано с переобучением. одна из первых вещей, которые можно сделать, это увеличить размер обучающего набора и применить регуляризацию

Comment: ну нормализацию-то попробовали?

Comment: а вот у вас там цифры или символы на входе?

Comment: очень похоже на то, что схема обучения не работает. Выкинул из обучающего множества почти все колонки, а train loss поменялся незначительно (в пределах погрешности). Как был 0,2-0,1 так и остался. Проблема в характере данных - возможно. Мало данных - разумеется. Но смущает то, что train loss не опускается ниже 0,09 даже после 200 эпох, даже с learning rate = 1e-6. При этом пробовал как "жирные", так и "тонкие" настройки нейросети. Картина приблизительно одинаковая: через 3-10 эпох loss стабилизируется в районе 0,2 и после этого начинает незначительно скакать вверх-вниз.

Comment: забейте на "свою" сеть пробуйте чужие примеры. потом адаптация к своей задаче. сначала без lstm, только dense, и потом уже с lstm-памятью.

Comment: @VladChapl GRU инициируется в каждом батче или эпохе?

Comment: GRU инициализируется в начале каждого батча. Пробовал в начале эпоху - у меня это не повлияло на точность. Предвижу, что общество удаленно не сможет помочь. **Просто пишите о трудностях обучения рекуррентных нейросетей и как их преодолевать**. Самый информативный ответ будет обозначен мною как решение.

Comment: Ну похоже у вас просто не на чём учиться нейросети. Данных мало и фичи не богатые информацией.

Comment: Мне такие метода прогноза напоминают об [анекдотах о чукчах и метеорологе](https://myanekdot.ru/anekdoti-pro-chukchu-i-meteorologa/)

Answer (score 0):

@nexoma пиши развернутый ответ про нормализацию (возможно с примерами из собственных опытов, где без нормализации всё хуже) - получишь баллы.

1. Хоть 90% данных были в диапазоне [-1..1] были колонки, которые сильно выходили за этот диапазон. Простое выкидывание таких колонок уже помогает (потом там, разумеется, будет нормирование).
2. batch_size вместо обычных 64 желательно ставить в моем случае 300 и даже 600 (а данных-то всего 800).
3. Обязательный контроль градиентов при помощи чего-то такого

   ```
        # Gradient Norm Clipping
        grd_norms  = nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=2, norm_type=2)

        if grd_norms > 1:
            logger.warning(f'Gradient problem grd_norms={grd_norms.item()}')
            nn.utils.clip_grad_value_(model.parameters(), clip_value=1.0)
   ```
4. Увеличение числа эпох до нескольких тысяч (у постепенным уменьшением learning rate до 1e-6).

Применение всего комплекса позволило **снизить train loss с 0,2 до 0,01** (дальше лень было ждать). Основной пункт первый, но только его мало (добавив только нормализацию loss падает примерно до 0,08).

Comment: На данном этапе была цель понизить именно train loss, т.к. на следующем этапе данных будет уже больше и тогда можно будет внимательнее смотреть test loss.